# How to mock service in groovy/src class under test with Grails 3.3.x

Tags: grails, spock, grails-3.3

I've recently upgraded to grails 3.3.1 and realised that `grails.test.mixin.Mock` has been pulled to separate project which has been build just for backward compatibility according to my understanding `org.grails:grails-test-mixins:3.3.0`.

I've been using `@Mock` annotation to mock Grails service injected into groovy/src class under test. What is the tactic to mock collaborating services in this case? Is there anything from Spock what I can use or should I fallback to grails-test-mixins plugin?

Class under test:
import gra

```
ils.util.Holders

import grails.util.Holders

class SomeUtilClass {

    static MyService myService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("myService")

    static String myMethod() {
        // here is some code
        return myService.myServiceMethod()
    }
}
```

My test spec (Grails 3.2.1):

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import spock.lang.Specification

@Mock([MyService])
class ValidatorUtilsTest extends Specification {

    def 'my test'() {
        when:
            def result = SomeUtilClass.myMethod()
        then:
            result == "result"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to you use Holders.grailsApplication in your SomeUtilClass, you can try to add @Integration annotation:

```
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import spock.lang.Specification
@Integration
class ValidatorUtilsTest extends Specification {

    def 'my test'() {
        when:
        def result = SomeUtilClass.myMethod()
        then:
        result == "result"
    }
}
```

Not sure, but hope it work for you.

Comment: Well, this is actually the cleanest solution for me as I want to test MyService as well. So integration service makes the most sense. Thanks...

Comment: It's really nice to hear this :D.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([your domains here])
class ValidatorUtilsTest extends Specification {

    static doWithSpring = {
       myService(MyService)
    }

    def 'my test'() {
        when:
            def result = SomeUtilClass.myMethod()
        then:
            result == "result"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't work as the dependency injection is done through Holders manually. It throws an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GrailsApplication not found`. I can still use @Mock what works. I was asking if there is another better way...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Mock` annotation and implement `ServiceUnitTest<MyService>` in your test class.